# Grails 2.4.4 SCSS support?

Tags: grails, sass, asset-pipeline

I added `sass-grails-asset-pipeline`, and in `main.gsp` I have this:
`<asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>`

If I change `stylesheets/application.css` to `stylesheets/application.scss`, the GSP produced creates no `<link>` to request the css. If I do a manual request for `http://localhost:8080/my-app/assets/application.css` I get a `404`.

What's going on? Is there some special undocumented setup to get SCSS working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're using a `sass-assets` plugin that exactly matches your `assets-plugin`. Mismatching will cause issues.